# Training loss is much higher than validation loss

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training, loss-function

I am trying to train a neural network with 2 hidden layers to perform a multi class classification of 3 different classes. There is a huge imbalance to the classes, with the distribution being around 80%, 13% and 7% for class 1, 2, and 3.

I am facing the issue where my training loss is much higher than my validation loss and my training accuracy is lower than validation accuracy. Moreover, the shapes of my training and validation loss curves are a little strange.

[image]

[image]

The data set I am using is not small, with around 200k rows of training data and 50k validation data. Currently, I am using a learning rate of 0.01, with 40 epochs and 50 nodes within each hidden layer.

Have been stuck on this for a while and not too sure where I am going wrong. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Hi @josephwong, welcome to the site. In your model, are you using dropout, batch normalization or any other element that changes its behaviour between training and inference modes?

Comment: Hi Noe, thanks! Nope i am not using any dropout or regularization, though I am using early stopping.